# How can I render template tags from a view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need to escape just part user input for output. For example

```
Hey a status update for <a href="/profile/2353">@Friend Name</a>
```

I just need to escape the link part of text in case someone does something like

```
<h1>HaCkEDED!!!!</h1>
```

So I can't escape the entire block. So I tried this

```
'{%% autoescape off %%} <a href="/profile/%s">%s</a>{%% endautoescape %%}' % (tag, at)
```

When I send this to output in the browser here is what I get

```
 {% autoescape off %} <a href="/profile/2353">@Friend Name</a>{% endautoescape %}
```

How can I get the autoescape to work? I can't use a separate variable and put

```
{{ tag | safe }}
```

because one post might have multiple tags and the tags will be in different spots. So how can I get Django to let me output one of its templates?

Comment: It's easy... but It is very ugly... For this reason, only a track: You should use the Template class http://dattatecblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/oh_my_god.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but in a view you can mark items as not needing autoescaping by using `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe`.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to output {% autoescape off %} from a view. This did exactly what I needed though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to do that using a [custom templatetag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/), probably with some [regex](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) which can identify the tags.